# How to create a model based on existing SQL table using ASP.NET Core v2 in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, scaffolding

I am using ASP.NET Core v2 with Visual Studio 2017 and would like to create a model class based on existing sql table.

If I try to add a new item using File->Add->New Scaffolding item I don't find any entry for creating a model. I only get controllers and Razorpages. I was expecitng an entry that would ask me for what server, database and table I would like to creata a model for

I have seen in some youtube videos that this was possible in earlier version or if not using core.

I know I can accomplish what I need by using NuGet and Scaffold-DbContext but would like to know why I can't find a way to do it using "add"

Comment: I think you might be referring to [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/).

Comment: well, maybe, there are options/add items for creating razorpages and controllers with EF, but then the model already need to exist.  doesn't really matter if dbcontext is created or not. I just need the model